# Simple way to test if the browser supports the Web Audio Api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, web-audio-api

Can anyone tell me a simple and reliable test (in javascript/jquery) for whether the current browser supports the Web Audio Api?  Needs to work on mobile.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Comment: `"AudioContext" in window`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you correctly...

```
var context;
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
function init() {
  try {
    // Fix up for prefixing
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();
  }
  catch(e) {
    alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
  }
}
```

That's taken directly from [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) (article by [Boris Smus](http://www.html5rocks.com/profiles/#smus)).

Comment: I guess he took it from here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to initialize a web audio context taking into account future implementations of the Web Audio API which don't exist yet. Taken from [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/web-audio-api/9781449332679/s01_2.html).

```
var contextClass = (window.AudioContext || 
  window.webkitAudioContext || 
  window.mozAudioContext || 
  window.oAudioContext || 
  window.msAudioContext);
if (contextClass) {
  // Web Audio API is available.
  var context = new contextClass();
} else {
  // Web Audio API is not available. Ask the user to use a supported browser.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @thanksd, i'll add this in as an alternative method and speak to our web audio guy about it.